# Unit Testing Issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have recently integrated XCTest into my project. It works fine when I run test cases using the play button in source editor or Using the play button in test navigator. My problem is, when I use the Test Button (The Spanner like symbol) in the ToolBar I am getting compilation errors.I already have integrated pods in my project and there is a static library created by me as well.

Note : During thorough checking I figure out all the compilation errors coming in the static library created by myself.The error count is too large so compiler shows "too much error" message

Is there any additional setup needed for including the static library into tests?

This issue arise only in case of testing I can succesfuly build and run the project

Thanks

Test Succeeded Here [image]

Compilation Error Here  [image]

Comment: Can you present the error messages, or at least some of them, if they are too many?

Comment: @waldrumpus Errors like Unknown Type CGFloat,  Unknown Type UIColor

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean build to see if xcode hasn't cached anything when you try to do a full test.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution finally, the issue is because of test target added as part of my custom library. When I try to run the test from toolbar xcode try to run all the unit test targets (My main project's test and my custom library's test case ). Library's test case can't run independently because it has some coupling with main project. Remove the test target and run test cases everything perfect.